# How to make a blueprintJs dialog draggable with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable, blueprint, react-big-calendar

I have a react-big-calendar and a button create, which when I click on it, I have a blueprint dialog will be open, I want this will be draggable anywhere.

My dialog is : 
[image]

My code is :

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-shockley-tt9bc

How to make it draggable ?

Comment: you can use react-rnd package for drag and resize.

Comment: @chauhanamit I used it, but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is:
1. Make the div of Dialog draggable as  
2. Apply onDrag event on the same div, and pass a function, and the function would do something like:

```
handleDragEvent = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        positionX: event.clientX,
        positionY: event.clientY,
    })
}
```

And then you need to give these cooridnates to your dialogues as a starting position. You may need some polishing on the above stated function as per your need.

Comment: How can use it on the dialog ?

Comment: When you inspect the model, you have a div with *class=bp3-overlay bp3-overlay-open bp3-overlay-scroll-container*, you have to override it and remove the *position:absolute* and remove it. and apply your own margining system. And apply margin-top and margin-left the same values as in state positionX and positionY.